# Exporting PDF with more image compression options

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts, pdf

I am trying to reduce the size of a PDF - but there is only two options, Lossy (JPEG) or Lossless:
[image: Compression options for PDF's]

However in other PDF printing software there are more algorithms to reduce the file size, below is an example from Foxit PDF (also free):

[image]

I have a few questions:

1. Is it possible to add additional options to compress the image to the QGIS print layout?
2. Is it possible to set the default export option in the layout to another PDF printer?

Comment: What QGIS version that is and where can I find those Export options?